# r - as.POSIXct returns unexpected NA (previous solutions don't apply to my case)

Tags: r, datetime-conversion

I have a dataset with 228 observations and, one of the three columns specifying "Date" is in the following form: 2 December 1999   4 November 1999   7 October 1999 .....
My aim is to convert it into this format: 1999-12-02 (yyyy-mm-dd). To do so, I use the "as.POSIXct" function but I get "NA" for all the 228 observations.

I tried this code and any possible variance of that (including some hints got from previous questions similar to mine) such as "as.Date", "strptime", etc.:

```
new_date <- as.POSIXct(ecb_result1$Date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
```

As I said, I expected to see the conversion from "2 December 1999" to "1999-12-02". Instead, I got:

```
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

Is there anyone who can help me understand what's wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Use the correct format `%d %B %Y`

Comment: @akrun no change, always NA

Comment: If the value showed is right, then I can't reproduce it `as.POSIXct("2 December 1999", format = "%d %B %Y")#
[1] "1999-12-02 EST"`

Comment: This is very interesting... I don't get it `as.POSIXct("2 December 1999", format = "%d %B %Y")
[1] NA`

Comment: Please check your locale settings.  If it is other than English/UnitedStates, then it would be a different one

Comment: You were right. Locale settings was the problem. Thanks a lot mate!

Answer (score 2):

The format for `as.Date` or `as.POSIXct` in this case is `"%e %B %Y"`. But this is locale dependent. In my case October is not transformed as my locale is dutch. And the format is expecting oktober not October. This might be happening in your case as well. I would suggest trying lubridate's `dmy` function. See examples below.

```
dates <- c("2 December 1999", "4 November 1999", "7 October 1999")

# goes wrong for my locale
as.Date(dates, "%e %B %Y") # as.Date
[1] "1999-12-02" "1999-11-04" NA

as.POSIXct(dates, format = "%e %B %Y") # as.POSIXct
[1] "1999-12-02 CET" "1999-11-04 CET" NA
```

But lubridate's `dmy` function does the trick for me.

```
lubridate::dmy(dates)
[1] "1999-12-02" "1999-11-04" "1999-10-07"
```

Or messing around with your Sys.setlocale will also work:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "English_United Kingdom")

as.POSIXct(dates, format = "%e %B %Y")
[1] "1999-12-02 CET"  "1999-11-04 CET"  "1999-10-07 CEST"
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Solved the problem with 'Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "English_United Kingdom")'. Thanks again a lot!